# Sequelize node.js сортирует только по первому числу

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Есть проблема. При рендеринге страницы мне нужно сортировать карточки ботов по количеству голосов пользователей (upvotes). Но сортировка идет только по первому числу, когда 9 голосов карточка бота на 1 месте,после 10 бот улетает в низ к другим с 1-0 голосами. Помогите мне пожалуйста  :(

```
     app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
        const FetchedBots = await client.database.Bots.findAll({
            where: { isApproved: true },
            order: [['totalUpvotes', 'NAME']]
        });
        const Bots = [];
        FetchedBots.map(bot => bot.dataValues).forEach(bot => {
            const Bot = client.users.cache.get(bot.botID);
            if(Bot) {
                bot.tag = `${Bot.username}`;
                bot.avatar = Bot.avatar;
                bot.upvotes = client.database.Upvotes.get(`${bot.botID}_upvotes_${new Date().toISOString().slice(1, 9999)}`);
                Bots.push(bot);
            }
        });
        res.render("Index.ejs", { bot: req.bot, user: (req.user || null), bots: _.chunk(Bots, 4) });
    });
```

Comment: totalUpvotes вычисляется или хранится? какого оно типа?

Comment: Впечатление, что totalUpvotes - строка

Comment: totalUpvotes хранится в столбике бд,я не предоставил полный код мой косяк

Comment: @янекодер какую субд вы используете? какого типа поле totalUpvotes? покажите структуру таблицы!